# Web2Py handle auth form at backend

Tags: python, authentication, web2py

The database model structure is as shown below.

**I want to present user with a registration form that asks for hostel_name and then at the backend convert the hostel_name to store it according hostel ID.**

controller/default.py

```
def user():
    return dict(form=auth())
```

models/db.py

```
db.define_table(
    'hostels',
    Field('hostel_admin_group_id', 'integer'),
    Field('hostel_residents_group_id', 'integer'),
    Field('hostel_name', length=32, unique=True),
 )


db.define_table(
    'users',
    Field('username', length=32, unique=True),
    Field('password', 'password', length=32, readable=False, label='Password'),
    Field('first_name', 'string', length=32, default=''),
    Field('last_name', 'string', length=32, default=''),
    Field('email_id', 'string', length=32),
    Field('degree_name', 'string', length=32),
    Field('hostel_id', db.hostels),
    Field('picture_id', 'integer'),
    Field('year_of_degree', 'integer'),
 )
```

views/user.html

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<h2>
{{=T('Sign Up') if request.args(0) == 'register' else T('Log In') if request.args(0) == 'login' else T(request.args(0).replace('_',' ').title())}}
</h2>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="web2py_user_form" class="col-lg-6">
        {{
        if request.args(0)=='login':
            if not 'register' in auth.settings.actions_disabled:
                form.add_button(T('Sign Up'),URL(args='register', vars={'_next': request.vars._next} if request.vars._next else None),_class='btn btn-default')
            pass
            if not 'request_reset_password' in auth.settings.actions_disabled:
                form.add_button(T('Lost Password'),URL(args='request_reset_password'),_class='btn btn-default')
            pass
        pass
        =form
        }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{{block page_js}}
<script>
    jQuery("#web2py_user_form input:visible:enabled:first").focus();
{{if request.args(0)=='register':}}
    web2py_validate_entropy(jQuery('#auth_user_password'),100);
{{elif request.args(0)=='change_password':}}
    web2py_validate_entropy(jQuery('#no_table_new_password'),100);
{{pass}}
</script>
{{end page_js}}
```

The above present code presents user with a registration form and expects user to enter the hostel id. What do I need to change to enable this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly define an `IS_IN_DB` validator for the `hostel_id` field, providing a `label` argument to specify labels to be used in the HTML select widget:

```
    Field('hostel_id', db.hostels,
          requires=IS_IN_DB(db, 'hostels.id', label='%(hostel_name)s'),
          represent=lambda ref, row: ref.hostel_name)
```

The `IS_IN_DB` validator will cause `SQLFORM` to generate a select widget for the field, and its `label` argument will result in the `hostel_name` field being used to generate labels for the widget, even though the actual `db.hostels.id` values will be inserted in the database.

The `represent` attribute specifies how values will be shown in read-only forms and in the grid.

Note, all of the above (both the `requires` and `represent` attributes) can be achieved more simply be just specifying the `format` argument when defining the `db.hostels` table:

```
db.define_table(
    'hostels',
    Field('hostel_admin_group_id', 'integer'),
    Field('hostel_residents_group_id', 'integer'),
    Field('hostel_name', length=32, unique=True),
    format='%(hostel_name)s')
```

With the above `format` argument, any tables that reference `db.hostels` will automatically get the `IS_IN_DB` validator and `represent` attribute as shown above.

Finally, if you intend to use the web2py Auth system, rather than creating your own `users` table, you should simply extend or re-define the standard `db.auth_user` table. This is explained [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Customizing-Auth). Also, for security purposes, you should not store passwords as plain text -- so you should use the `CRYPT` validator with the password field (the standard `db.auth_user` table does this automatically).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. Was badly stuck at this. I have begun learning web2py only today and did not realize unto now how format could be used. Many thanks to you. 
Can you please look at another one of my queries. I am trying to make a rest api using web2py and I am already fascinated by the ease it provides. But few of my defined apis are misbehaving. Please look at the link below for more details

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235871/web2py-rest-api-endpoint-gives-invalid-path-output